# Pandas cut with user-defined bins

Tags: python, pandas, cut

I am working in Python and using the cut functionality in Pandas. I would like to have the bins in my pd.cut to be based on user-defined comma separated integers, with predefined top and bottom bounds. In other words, I would like to predefine `bins` as `[0, 100000]` and then append user defined integers to this set of numbers. If the user entered `5, 100, 5000` then `bins` would become `[0, 5, 100, 5000, 100000]` and would then work with `pd.cut(df['Quantity'], bins`.

I have tried a number of solutions with no avail up to this point - any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
bin_range = [0, 100000]
bin_input = raw_input("Enter bins as comma seperated list")
bin_input_parsed = [int(x.strip()) for x in bin_input.split(',')]

bins = [bin_range[0]] + bin_input_parsed + [bin_range[1]]
pd.cut(df['Quantity'], bins)
```